# Add Javascript to wordpress for every page except admin

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Looking for help on inserting this code via functions.php or anywhere else in Wordpress. I tried this and it does not seem work... I cannot see it in the source code

```
<?php
 function add_this_script_footer(){ ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var _paq = _paq || [];
        _paq.push(["trackPageView"]);
        _paq.push(["enableLinkTracking"]);


        (function() {
        var u=(("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https" : "http") + "://stats.domain.com/statsapp/";
        _paq.push(["setTrackerUrl", u+"piwik.php"]);
        _paq.push(["setSiteId", "445"]);
        var d=document, g=d.createElement("script"), s=d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]; g.type="text/javascript";
        g.defer=true; g.async=true; g.src=u+"piwik.js"; s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s);
        })();
    </script>    <?php }

add_action('wp_footer', 'add_this_script_footer'); ?>
```

Thank-you for your help.

`

Comment: Belongs on: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add it to template file - either to the header.php or footer.php

Comment: Tried that, it did not work.. I added  it to the footer.php in the theme-compat folder, is this the correct folder?

Comment: It has to be /wp-content/themes/(name of active theme)/footer.php or header.php but if you put it in footer.php, it should be right before </body> closing tag. Just to be clear - you want to add only the <script> part, not the php code.

Answer (score 2):

The "correct" way to do it would be to use wp_enqueue_script and put the code in its own js file.

So, take the tracking code and save it in a file like site-tracking.js.

Then in your functions.php file do something like:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_scripts');

function my_custom_scripts(){
  /** here you can apply whatever logic you want to determine which pages
   *  your script gets included on, like wrap this in is_singular()
   */
  wp_enqueue_script('tracking', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/site-tracking.js', array(), '', null, true);

}
```

This way your javascript gets properly enqueued, you can update it in a single, self-contained file and you and unregister as needed.

Comment: where do I add this code, functions.php in the wp-includes folder ?, and can I use this for path to root :     get_bloginfo(url).'/piwik-script.js

Comment: Add it in your theme's functions.php file. In this example, you'd have a folder called js inside your theme folder. The path you're using would mean your js file is in the root folder of WP. You want it in wp-content/themes/your-theme/js

Comment: I have 3 folders in the wp-content> delicate, twentyeleven and twentyten how can I know which one it is, I will be doing this for several websites is there a way to tell without loggin into the admin of each site?

Comment: View Source in your browser -- your stylesheet links will show you which folder. Something like: <link rel=stylesheet href='http://yoursite.com/wp-content/themes/theme_name/... >

Answer (score 2):

The most flexible method is to use a custom function in your child themes functions file using the [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) function and customize the parameters.

**Dependant On jQuery**

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'child_enqueue_scripts' );

function child_enqueue_scripts() {

if ( ! is_admin() ) {

wp_register_script( 'script-handle', get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) . '/your.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );

wp_enqueue_script( 'script-handle' );

    }
}
```

Once you [register the script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script), you can use the script-handle in other code in your files without the need to register it again.

Set the 5th parameter **$in_footer** to true for execution in the footer if you want the script to be placed before the  end tag. 
Default: false

This method enables you to use WordPress and theme specific hooks with conditional tags which is more flexible than adding the script in a template file.

**Child Themes Versus Parent Themes**

Change

```
get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' )
```

Or

```
get_stylesheet_directory_uri()
```

To

```
get_template_directory_uri()
```

When adding scripts in parent themes.

**No Dependencies**

Use this below example in your child themes functions file for scripts with no dependencies ( like Tracking scripts ) which don't rely on jQuery.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'no_dependencies_enqueue_scripts' );

function no_dependencies_enqueue_scripts() {

if ( ! is_admin() ) {

wp_register_script( 'script-handle', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/your.js', false, '1.0.0', true );

wp_enqueue_script( 'script-handle' );

    }

}
```

**Note:** Both code examples assume your file containing your script is located in the root directory of your child theme. Change this path if you added the script files in a separate folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`wp_add_inline_script`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_script/) if you want to add inline JavaScript code:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
    wp_register_script( 'foobar', '',);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'foobar' );
    wp_add_inline_script( 'foobar', "console.log('hello world');");
} );
```

If you want to make jQuery a dependency, then change the second line to:

```
    wp_register_script( 'foobar', '', ['jquery'], '', true );
```